# VB detect a difference between days

Tags: vba

I was looking for in a variety of topics, but not found the answer so I ask: 
  Is it possible to detect the difference between the day in VB?. I mean,  I run the program on Monday and he will say to me today is Monday and is day difference ( yesterday was a Sunday) and the variables will be reset, and so for each day so that the variables are valid for one day.

Comment: Sure, you can store the last execution date in database, a file, the settings of the app, etc. What you've tried or which problem do you have? Do you need help calculating the difference or storing the date? Please show what you've tried so we can help you better

Comment: what i tried to do and i want to do . I describe my reasoning, i have a application which can execute vb script and i can set in this application store value of the variable( when i close app and run again variable hold value), but i want reset this variable next day but i can't set automatic variable reset after 24 hours in settings application so i think to use vb script to reset variable nex day. So when

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this (cant remember if you can declare todays date like this in vb.net, but rest of the code should be sound):

```
dim tDay as datetime = now()
Select Case tDay.DayOfWeek
Case DayOfWeek.Monday
'Its Monday
Case DayOfWeek.Tuesday
'Its Tuesday
.
.
.
.
End Select
```

Its untested, but will get you on the right lines

EDIT:
To check if the date has changed and reassign your variables, declare the variables for your date and your x as system settings (`My.Settings`).
Then, from there its a case of adding to the above:

```
Case DayOfWeek.Monday
If My.Settings.weekDayCheck <> DayOfWeek.Monday Then
My.Settings.weekDayCheck = DayOfWeek.Monday
My.Settings.x = 20
Else
My.Settings.x = My.Settings.x + 1
End If
```

and so on

Comment: thanks for the reply but that's not what I meant, I want to program itself detected after start, it is the next day so will delete variables, such as today at 10:00 am, i add to the variable "x" number and a variable "x"=20, then again run the program at 9:00 pm and is increase by one so variable "x" = 21,then I want to make the program resets the variable the next day ,so when i  run the program tomorrow at 10 am, the variable "x" = 0 again

Comment: Actually, it would work just fine. Will modify example now to show this

Answer (score 0):

Tough question.  It sounds like you need to store the state of the program between executions.  You can do this by saving the data to disk, e.g. by using Serialization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and then Deserializing it (if it exists on disk) the next time the program is loaded.

From that point on, it's just a case of checking against yesterday's date:

```
Sub Main
    Dim storedDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(storedDate.Date).TotalDays)
End Sub
```

Here's an example:

```
Sub Main
    Dim state As new State()

    StateHelper.SaveState("C:\\Users\\a-h\\test.xml", state)
    state = StateHelper.LoadState("C:\\Users\\a-h\\test.xml")

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Date.Subtract(state.DateLastAccessed.Date).TotalDays)
End Sub

Class StateHelper
    Shared Sub SaveState (ByVal fileName As String, ByVal state As State)
        Dim serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType(State))  

        Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)
            serializer.Serialize(fs, state)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Shared Function LoadState (ByVal fileName As String) As State
        If File.Exists(fileName)
            Dim serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType(State))  

            Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)
                Return serializer.Deserialize(fs)
            End Using
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function 
End Class

Class State
    Property DateLastAccessed As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Property Name As String = Environment.UserName
End Class
```

Comment: still it's not anwser i am looking for, So I have an app (not created by me), which is able to perform a VBA script,in variable settings i can  specify that the variable will retentive (like turn off and run again  program variable hold  value.) Now I would like to make value was kept for one day in the program, eg if on Monday at 10 am run the program and increase the value of the variable, so that x = 10 and then run again program at 10 pm and increase variable  it will be x = 11, but when run  program Tuesday at 10:15 am variable x=0 and the increase of 1  x = 1, i want hold var one day